# Sort ListView by Date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a WPF ListView with a column that has dates in it.  I would like a way to custom sort the dates (by date value, rather than string value).  Is there a way to do this?  Right now I am using list.Items.SortDescriptions to sort using another column, but I would like to change this to sort on the date column instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried that ?

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Date", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

EDIT: You can also have a look at [this attached property](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/27/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-when-a-column-header-is-clicked/)

Comment: Yes I see that now.  Maybe I was afraid it would just do string comparison.  I made a property that converted my string date to a date object and it's working well.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if we can do that using XAML?

Comment: Sure, have a look at the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

Comment: ok thx. I don't think the example are very clear but I get the point I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you're finding that the way WPF is sorting by default isn't what you intended, you can provide a custom sorter to the default view:

```
ListCollectionView view = 
  (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
view.CustomSort = new DateValueSorter();
listView.Items.Refresh();
```

Where DateValueSorter is a class that implements the IComparer interface and sorts according to the date value and produces the ordering you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use ObservableList and a custom object type - and do the sorting yourself. Connect the ListView to the ObservableList using ItemsSource.

..., or you could try doing what this blog describes; [Sorting ListViews](http://mbrownchicago.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!2221DC39E0C749A4!331.entry)